# Javascript Date/Time Check Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wikitude

using the following code in my application to display html pages depending on it being todays date and also which time of the day it is e.g morning, afternoon or evening. Currently it is 2:53pm and the code is only displaying the am html page (which is the first one). I tried to run the console.log command but got nothing in the console which could be because of wikitude.

The first function of getting the date is working correctly it is just not checking the time correctly.

```
var inputDate = new Date("5/17/2018");

    // Get today's date
    var todaysDate = new Date();

      // call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
      if(inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
          var hour = new Date().getHours();

          console.log("hour is: " + hour);
                    // between 12 PM and 7 AM respectively
            if(hour => 7 && hour < 12) {
                //morning   (Always running code here no matter what time of day) 
            }
            else if(hour >= 12 && hour <= 18) {
               //afternoon   
            }   
            else {

            //evening or before 7
            }
      }
      else{
           //not today (works if date is not today)
      }
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal code example showing the problem you're facing.

Comment: I have edited out the code, you can see the issue now. No matter what time of the day it displays the morning code, although if it isn't todays date it displays the not today correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the `if` statement: `=>` should be `>=`

```
var inputDate = new Date("5/17/2018");

// Get today's date
var todaysDate = new Date();

// call setHours to take the time out of the comparison
if (inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
  var hour = new Date().getHours();

  console.log("hour is: " + hour);
  // between 12 PM and 7 AM respectively
  if (hour >= 7 && hour < 12) {
    //morning   (Always displaying code here) 
    alert('morning')
  }
  else if (hour >= 12 && hour <= 18) {
    //afternoon
    alert('afternoon')
  }   
  else {
    //evening or before 7
    alert('evening')
  }
}
else {
  //not today
  alert('not today')
}
```